# CDKTF Init Issue

Tags: typescript, terraform, terraform-cdk

I am continuously getting this error when `cdktf init --template=typescript --local`.

```
[2023-11-04T01:00:18.860] [ERROR] default - Unable to request pre-built provider information: Network error, please check if you're connected to the internet and try again
Connection error
Error: Connection error
    at mNt (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:181:1998)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async yF (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:181:1658)
    at async xjt (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:513:3000)
    at async lje (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:513:1337)
    at async Object.uGe (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:513:30497)
    at async Vg.handleCommand (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cdktf.js:60:16625)
    at async L.handler (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cdktf.js:60:15026)
Collecting Debug Information...
/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: Connection error
    at mNt (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:181:1998)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async yF (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:181:1658)
    at async xjt (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:513:3000)
    at async lje (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:513:1337)
    at async Object.uGe (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:513:30497)
    at async Vg.handleCommand (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cdktf.js:60:16625)
    at async L.handler (/Users/amandugar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cdktf.js:60:15026)
```

I have an good internet connection. Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening as part of the pre-built provider installation. I would start out with `cdktf init --template=typescript --local` and not select any pre-built providers in the terminal UI. That should get you around the issue and `cdktf provider add` can help you add the providers after you created your project (or you can add them manually if that does not work).